# How to remove horizontal scroll from grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a Grid Panel in ExtJs 3.4 app:

```
kad_tab = new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    region: 'center',
    cm: cm, 
    selModel: new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.RowSelectionModel(),
    stripeRows : true,
    view: myView,
    //height: 390,
    loadMask: true,
    id: 'kad_tab',
    autoExpandColumn:'cadColumn',
    title:'Земельные участки',
    autoWidth:true,
    autoScroll: true,
```

And view:

```
    var myView = new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.GridView({
    nearLimit : 70,
    autoFill: true,
    scrollOffset: 0,
    loadMask  : {
        msg :  'Buffering. Please wait...'
    }
});
```

And how its look:

[image]

You see that there some problem with last row. I think its becouse horizontal scroll.
Its possible to remove horizontal scroll?

Comment: @A1rPun: It's not work.

Comment: forceFit: true inside viewConfig

Comment: @sushant jain: Its work. If you make answer from your comment i'll accept this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
forceFit: true
```

inside viewConfig of the grid

Answer (score 2):

use style:{overflowX:'hidden'} or {'overflow-x':'hidden'}.

'**hidden**' should be the class.

and also try **autoscroll:false**

Comment: `autoscroll:false` not help. And where i can write `{'overflow-x':'hidden'}. `?